# ヘルプページの「検索方法」に "削除された投稿" に関する説明を追記したい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターの「検索方法」の説明において、[英語版](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) ではページの末尾に "Deleted Posts" という段落がある一方、[日本語版](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) ではこの段落が存在しません。

説明が記載されていないだけで、実際には (信用度の条件を満たしていれば) 機能を使うことができる状態なので、ヘルプページにも説明を追記したいです。

**参考: 英語版での説明文**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 4):

翻訳した追記案を回答として投稿します。英語版での説明から変更したのは以下の項目です。

- 必要となる信用度がサイトごとに異なる (ベータサイト扱いの日本語版では 2,000)

---

### 翻訳案

#### 削除された投稿 (信用度 2,000 が必要)

[モデレーターツールへのアクセス](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) 権限を取得すると、`deleted:` 演算子を使用して (自分自身の) 削除された投稿を検索できます。

- `deleted:1` 削除された投稿のみを検索します。
- `deleted:all` 自分自身が作成した、削除済みの投稿と削除されていない投稿の両方を検索します。
- `deleted:0` 自分が自身が作成した、削除されていない投稿のみを検索します。 (`user:me` と実質的に同じ動作)

なお、[サイト モデレーター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) はこの演算子を使用して、他のユーザーが所有している投稿を含む、サイト上のすべての投稿を検索できます。